# Implementing custom protocol logic in Java?

Tags: java, protocols, state-machine

When implementing a client/server solutions, one of the questions you always need to answer is about protocol.

In simple cases, it's possible that packets are always of the same type, so the protocol could even have no logic at all: client connects to the server and sever just says some fact, the client disconnects and that's it.

In more complex cases, some packets are can only be sent in some specific cases. For instance, imagine an abstract server that requires authorization: clients *have to* authorized before sending or getting any useful data. In this case, the concept of session appears.

Session is an concept that describes the state of client/server dialog: both client and sever *expect* something from eachother, while there are also things that both of them don't expect.

Then, *going even deeper*, pretend that protocol is quite complicated and it's implementation should be easily extendable. I believe, that the theoretically right solution here is using a finite state machine. Are there any Java frameworks/libraries that allow this state machine to be easily implemented? Or probably, any more protocol-specific solutions?

What I'm expecting is a framework that allows me to define states and transitions between them.

**Update**: the question is not about easiest client/server solution implementation, the question is about implementing custom protocol. So, please, don't recommend using web services.

Comment: Have you consider using of web-services or something similar? You don't have to implement your own solution, you could use WS as already proven approach.

Comment: Well, let's just add a constraint that doesn't allow me to use WS in this task :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember using [Unimod FSM](http://unimod.sourceforge.net/fsm-framework.html) for finite state machines a few years ago, although for serious work I always preferred to implement the finite state machines directly.